# Windows Phone Launchers and choosers

Tags: windows-phone-7

I had a couple of queries about the windows phone 7 launcher tasks, Specifically a phonecalltask.

1) Does PhonecallTask Show() launch an application?

2) If so, What happens to the calling application? Does it go dormant or run on separate threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks shelve the currently running application and run the ms supplied apps to make calls, play videos, send sms, email etc.

When you are in a task it will "Tombstone" your application so that you can save the data you need for when it recovers.

Answer (score 0):

Showing a PhoneCallTask can be compared to receiving a phone call while in your application.